# Should non-QObject derived classes "always" be put on the stack?

Tags: qt, memory-management, qobject, qstring

Coming from the Symbian world, I'm used to using the heap as much as possible to avoid running out of stack space, especially when handling descriptors. CBase derived classes were always dynamically allocated on the heap, since if they were not, their member variables would stay uninitialized. Does the same convention apply to QObject-derived classes?

In Qt it seems to be common to put, for example QString, on the stack. Are the string contents put on the heap while QString acts as a container on the stack, or is everything put on the stack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As sje397 said: It's idiomatic to put `QString` and containers on the stack, as they are implicitly shared. Their internals (pimpl idiom "d" pointer) are created on the heap. There is no point in creating the object itself on the heap, too. Just causes memory-management hassles and you lose the intended copy-on-write properties when passing pointers to strings/containers around.

`QObjects` on the other hand you want to create on the heap in almost all cases, as otherwise they would be destructed again right away. They can't be copied or assigned (well, one can enforce it for own subclasses, but the `QObject` semantics are broken then), and usually they are supposed to survive the method body they are created in.
Exception is `QDialog`, which is often created on the stack, followed by `QDialog::exec`, which blocks until the dialog is closed. But even that is strictly spoken unsafe, as external events (RPC calls, background operations) could cause the dialog to be deleted by its parent (if the parent itself is deleted) before exec returns. 
Then having the dialog created on the stack will cause double deletion when unwinding the stack -> crash.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. It, together with sje397's link cleared up my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

QString, and many other Qt classes, use [implicit data sharing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/shared.html). That implies that memory is generally allocated on the heap.